# Flutter and firebase database connects only when provided with database URL

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to connect to Firebase realtime database and couldn't update/read data. I was using `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()` to gain reference but apparently couldn't access it. After a while I found out I can use `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instanceFor(app: myApp, databaseURL: myUrl).ref()` and it worked. Although I had `URL` in `google_services.json`.

```
"project_info": {
    "firebase_url": "url to my database that is displayed in console"
}
```

Why does my app does not recognize Firebase realtime database when not provided with `URL` on instance? `Firestore` and `FirebaseAuth` works just fine.

Comment: could you check "module: build gradle " file is  there' `id 'com.google.gms.google-services'`? Also do you have correct needed dependencies  for access it on gradle dependencies

Comment: @samsa I do have dependencies